# Switch auto-fill-mode in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to make keyboard shortcut for toggling `auto-fill-mode` on or off.
In my `~/.emacs` I have

```
(setq-default auto-fill-function 'do-auto-fill)
```

Now I tried to solve my problem using this function:

```
(defun my-switch-auto-fill-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (if (auto-fill-function)
      (auto-fill-mode 0)
    (auto-fill-mode 1)))
```

But it does not work..

Comment: What's wrong with `(local-set-key (kbd "<f2>") 'auto-fill-mode)`?

Comment: @HåkonHægland The best solution for your actual problem is that one from abo-abo.
The problems of your code are: (1) You want to test `auto-fill-function` and not `(auto-fill-function)`; (2) You do not reset `auto-fill-function` in the if-branch.

Comment: @abo-abo: Please, post your comment as answer. HåkonHægland: Please, accept abo-abo's answer as solution. This will mark this question as resolved.

Comment: @Tobias Yes, It would be nice if someone could give an answer and explain this confusion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple thing like will work:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f2>") 'auto-fill-mode)
```

However, calling

```
(auto-fill-mode)
```

only turns it on.
To toggle it from lisp code, use:

```
(call-interactively 'auto-fill-mode)
```

Comment: Or `(auto-file-mode 'toggle)`, which is the standard way to toggle minor modes from Lisp.  Even though the docstring of `auto-fill-mode` doesn't mention it, all proper minor modes (i.e. those defined with `define-minor-mode`) support this argument.